# Equal spacing of 3 divs inside of container

Tags: html, css

The container is 1200px, each div is only 292px wide. Ideally div 1 would sit on the left margin, div 3 would sit on the right margin and div 2 would sit right in the middle of them. To further complicate things, when viewed on mobile the container will be reduced to 320px and all 3 divs should be in line with each other vertically, underneath each other. At the moment the css to each div looks like this:

```
.test1 {
float:left;
width:292px;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
margin:0 4px 5px;
border:1px solid grey;
line-height:0;
}
```

Comment: Use `width: 33%;` and set `box-sizing: border-box;` and get rid of the margins

Comment: I don't want the divs to go any bigger than 292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved different ways depending on your html structure.

**with `float`:**

```
  <tag left   :floatleft  />
  <tag right  :float:right/>
  <tag center :margin:auto/>
```

---

**with `display:flex;`**

```
<parent 
       style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;">
  <child left   />
  <child center />
  <child right  />
</parent>
```

---

with `@media` queries you can swap row layout into column layout when width is not enough to hold the 3 of them : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/CDdjH)**

```
section {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
article {
  width:292px;
  background:green;
}
@media all and (max-width:900px) {
  section {
    flex-direction:column ;
  }
  article {width:100%;
  }
}
```

```
<section>
  <article> 292px width</article>
  <article> 292px width</article>
  <article> 292px width</article>
</section>
```

---

**with `display:inline-block`:**

```
<parent 
       style="text-align:center">
  <child left    style="display:inline-block"/>
  <child center  style="display:inline-block"/>
  <child right   style="display:inline-block"/>
  <pseudo-tag    style="display:inline-block;width:100%"/><!--this can be either a pseudo element or a neutral tag in HTML to enhance compatibility for IEs<8 -->
</parent>
```

Here a code pen to easily set and resize 3 boxes 292px width : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nrbDl

Comment: Your second example works perfectly, until we get to widths lower than the sum of the child widths. When there isn't enough space to fit them all on one line they should stack vertically.

Comment: to stack them as a column, you need mediaquery to add flex-direction:column when width is below about 900px. I'll set an example

Comment: @user3589055 to swap with mediaqueries the flex-direction : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/CDdjH

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-align:justify` on the container, this way it will work no matter how many elements you have in your container (you don't have to work out % widths for each list item

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/xrpMk/1/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test1"></div>
    <div class="test1"></div>
    <div class="test1"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.container:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.container .test1{
    display: inline-block;
    width:292px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    margin:0 4px 5px;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
}
.test1 {
    float:left;
    width: 24.333333333%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    margin-left:13.3%;
    border:1px solid grey;
    line-height:0;
}

.test1:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRbeV/1/)